# Присвоение значений в цикле

Tags: javascript, циклы

Есть код:

```
var divCommitSecond = document.createElement('div');
for (var i = 0; i < commitlist.length; i++) {
    divCommitSecond.innerHTML = '<hr><div><b>Коммит: </b>' +
            commitlist[i]['commit']['message'] + '<br> <b>Пользователь оставивший коммит: ' +
            commitlist[i]['committer']['login'] + '</b></div>';
}
closestF(commitsList, 'marginli').appendChild(divCommitSecond);
```

Он возвращает всего 1 строку, хотя если сделать проверку через

```
console.log(commitlist[i]['commit']['message']);
```

то вернет правильное количество. В чём я допустил ошибку?

Comment: ну так `divCommitSecond.innerHTML = ...` - вы же каждый раз заменяете значение, а не добавляете к нему, отсюда и ошибка

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ошибка в собирании строки.

Используется присваивание `=`, то есть на каждой итерации цикла значение `divCommitSecond.innerHTML` затирается.

Для решения можно использовать `+=`, либо сначала создать всю строку и только потом присвоить.

Например, так как `commitlist`, судя по всему, массив, можно использовать функцию `map`:

```
divCommitSecond.innerHTML = commitlist.map(function(commit) {
    return '<hr><div><b>Коммит: </b>' + commit['commit']['message'] +
           '<br> <b>Пользователь оставивший коммит: ' +
           commit['committer']['login'] + '</b></div>';
}).join('');
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо.  :-)